# python: testing the outputs ( ... not unit testing ?)

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests

I have a python script called `script.py`, this need a input `A` and generate a output `B`.

```
A -> script.py -> B
```

every time I add a new feature, I need to check that the program generate the same output.

how I can automated this tests type ?

what is the name of this tests type ?

exists some python module for this  tests type ?

Comment: something like this, `mv B _B; python script.py A; diff B _B`

Comment: @theAlse , yes, I'm thinking in some similar ... maybe a automated diff process. But for not reinvent the wheel, I'm searching more opinions about practices and modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand,
You want to test if that piece of code (unit) is doing what it's supposed to. **That's Unit Testing.**

What you can do is make a test that gives `script.py` it's input (`A`), and gets the output produced. Then you can just check if the output matches.

```
class OutputTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def get_output(self, input):
       ...  # You haven't mentioned how "input" is taken or how output is taken.

    def test_script(self):
       input = ...
       expected = ...

       output = self.get_output(input)
       self.assertEqual(output, expected)
```

PS: That's how [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) tests it's code. And I'm fiddling with it!

Answer (score 0):

You can write an [except](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) script to automate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pytest`](http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html) for your testing. So what you can do is create a `testing_suite.py` and put your tests in it with name starting as `test_` for ex: test_B, test_C etc

```
# testing_suite.py
import pytest

def test_B:
          proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'script.py',  'arg1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
          output = proc.communicate()[0]
          if output == 'B':
                     print "testB done" # or something else depends on you

def test_C:
          ....
          ....
```

then you can run as:

```
$> py.test
```

So this should execute all tests with `test_`. Please check [pytest doc here for test discovery rules](http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html#test-discovery).